# FlatList moves/drags in all directions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

When I click on my FlatList I can drag and move it in all directions (up/down/right left). Although the list appears to be vertical (maybe because of the styling), the scroll bar still appears horizontally. How can I disable this dragging?

This is how I am using the FlatList:

```
<FlatList
              data={data.me.friends.nodes}
              //horizontal={false}
              //scrollEnabled={false}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <FriendItem friend={item} originatorId={data.me.id}/>
              )}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
              ListEmptyComponent={NoFriendsContainer}
            />
```

This is from the FriendItem's return

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('FriendDetails')
        }>
        <Thumbnail
          style={styles.thumbnail}
          source={{
            uri:
              'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/person-512.png',
          }}></Thumbnail>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.deleteButtonContainer}>
        <Button
          rounded
          style={styles.deleteButton}
          onPress={() => onDeleteFriend(originatorId, friend.id)}>
          <Icon name="trash-o" size={moderateScale(20)} color="black" />
        </Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Styles for FriendItem:

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: moderateScale(20),
    padding: moderateScale(20),
    marginVertical: moderateScale(8),
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    height: moderateScale(110),
    width: moderateScale(360),
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  userName: {
    paddingRight: 55,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  deleteButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#31C283',
    width: moderateScale(45),
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  deleteButtonContainer: {
    paddingTop: 12,
    marginRight: 2,
  },
  thumbnail: {
    height: 85,
    width: 85,
    marginLeft: 2,
    paddingRight: 0,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  nameContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});
```

I also tried removing the TouchableOpacity but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

What you can try. is below :

UPDATE:

```
<Flatlist    
    bounces={false}/>
```

try this here, or add  bounces={false} in the top scrollView if its there

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Doesn't work. If I use this, I can no longer move items up and down but I can still move them right or left. I should be able to scroll down vertically. Currently I can't do that and the scroll bar is also horizontal

Comment: Nope. If I use this, I can no longer move items up and down but I can still move them right or left (not as freely as before tho. Just a little bit). I should be able to scroll down vertically. Currently I can't do that and the scroll bar is also horizontal

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened because of some times you have given a width to the parent view of flat list. like below.

```
<View style={{width: '90%'}}>
  <FlatList/>
</View>
```

simply add the flatlist to the same width with bounces false.

```
<View style={{width: '90%'}}>
  <FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{width: '90%'}}
    bounces={false}
  />
</View>
```

by adding bounces=false, your flatlist will not be able drag to different directions.